# Cómo llenar una matriz de NxN con ceros

Tags: python

Le quiero llenar de esta manera pero no se me ocurre nada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado con esto pero no me funciona:

```py
filas=int(input ("Introduce número de filas x columnas: "))
while filas%2==1:
    filas=int(input ("Introduce número de filas x columnas: "))
    print('El numero que ha ingresado es impar, intentelo nuevamente')
else:
    columnas=filas
    matriz= [[0] * columnas] * filas
    for i in matriz:print(i)
    Valores= input('Ingrese los valores correspondientes ')
    a=Valores.split(',')
    print(a)
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta? Por favor, adjunta el código como texto, no en imágenes.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 1):

Digamos que en `values` dejas los valores ingresados:

```
values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

para recorrer la matriz en el orden descrito, partes de las coordenadas (3, 3), colocas un valor en la matriz, y luego retrocedes una fila. Sigues asi hasta llegar a la fila cero, donde retrocedes una columna y vuelves a partir de la última fila. Sigues asi hasta que te pases de la columna cero, fila cero.

```
# matriz de 4*4 ha sido previamente inicializada.
dim = 4  # Una matriz de n * n
col = dim - 1 # Indice última columna
row = dim - 1 # Indice última fila
while col >= 0 and row >= 0:
    matriz[row][col] = values.pop(0)
    
    row -= 1  # Retroceder una fila
    if row < 0:
        row = dim - 1 # Volver a la última fila
        col -= 1      # Retroceder una columna

# Imprimir
for row in matriz:
    print(*row)
```

produce

```
15 11 7 3
14 10 6 2
13 9 5 1
12 8 4 0
```